# how to use date diff() function in checking if the issue date is earlier than receive date

Tags: php

i have a table named 'issue', which has a field name date. I want to issue an item but the date should not earlier than the date it was stocked which is in another table called 'receive'. Basically i have check two dates, one is in a table another will be entered by the user to different table and if the date entered by the user is earlier than date on receive table then it echo an error.

Comment: You don't need to use diff to determine if one date is before or after another. Construct a DateTime object for each of the dates you want to compare, then compare them using regular comparison operators (< or >).

Answer (score 1):

Once you retrieve the date-time string from your table, you can create DataTime objects which support comparison using the standard comparison operators as of PHP 5.2.2.

```
$dateTime1 = new DateTime('2017-05-26 05:30:21');
$dateTime2 = new DateTime('2017-05-25 01:02:03');

if ($dateTime1<$dateTime2){
    //Stuff to do if dateTime1 comes before dateTime2...
} else {
    //Stuff to do if dateTime2 comes before or is equal to dateTime1...
}
```

More info on this at: [PHP DateTime::diff documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: $issued_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['issued_to']);
$issued_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['issued_date']);

$query="SELECT date from recieve where asset_id='$asset_id'"
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$details=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($details['date']<'$issued_date');
{
   //execute next query
   }else{
   echo "invalid issue date";
   }                                        //will this work ??

Answer (score 0):

```
`
$issued_to = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['issued_to']);
$issued_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['issued_date']);
$query="SELECT date from recieve where asset_id='$asset_id'"
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$details=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($details['date']<'$issued_date');
{
//execute next query
}else{
echo "invalid issue date";
}`    //will this work ??
```